# Unable to fetch connection list and profile information via linkedin API #linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, openid, linkedin-j

I have created a LinkedIn developers account, I wanted to fetch my profile data and the first-degree connection list.
The official document says you have to add things in scope and I have to enable it over the LinkedIn app page also. But parameters like "r_liteprofile", and "r_network" are not visible, hence I am unable to set the scope. This is blocking me to fetch the connection list. Please help me out here.
I am attaching the screenshot of the scopes currently visible under my account.
[image]#linkedin